# One way replication - Parent Database read only access

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, replication

I am planning to setup one way replication from parent to child . My team only has read access to the parent database (SQL server) and child database is our own managed sql server.

Is it possible to setup one way replica with read only access to parent? If not, what are my other options?

Comment: A one-way replica is a Copy of your database... if there's no check-in then there's no need for transactional versioning. Why do you need to setup replication to achieve what is essentially a snapshot?

Comment: Can a create a snapshot of the parent/source database (in a different server with read only access) in a different server which is managed and I have db_owner access?

Comment: Yes, there are several different ways. One is to simply copy the entire workspace with ArcCatalog, overwriting existing as needed. Another way is indeed with replication, creating a snapshot of SDE -> SDE using Geodatabase Archiving http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000rs000000 which should keep updating from parent to child. I've not had 2 SDE environments to play with, mostly I use SDE -> fGDB replication as a check-out (edits in fGDB can be reconciled to SDE) but you can also not enable disconnected editing, creating a snapshot to a file database.

Comment: I added a tag for [tag:enterprise-geodatabase] to this question thinking that it was a geodatabase replication question rather than an SQL Server database replication.  Which are you using?

Comment: Any option either SDE replication or SQL server database replication will work- as long as I can replicate some tables from a non-spatial database (with read only access) to an enterprise geodatabase (with sa access).